# One out of two times my app crashes and freezes at splash page

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I'm still in development with my app and each time I "run" the app it crashes one out of two times. When it crashes the app freezes on the splash page and this is the error I get:

http://d.pr/i/rHjY

Could it be something to do with the splash page? It's just so odd that the app crashes one out of two times. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: What version of the tools are you using? There was a bug with old versions of the Xcode which caused apps to crash every other time when run in the simulator.

Comment: I'm using xCode 4.6 atm. Haven't updated yet since i'm making an app actually for iOS6. Doesn't matter if it's iOS6 or 7 since everything is customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using slightly older tools it might be related to this:

http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/

> The issue occurs to a process race condition for debugserver. Instead
>   of using GDB, you can alternatively kill your execution, wait a few
>   seconds for the app to wrap up, and then run the next iteration.

The quick fix:

> Update your scheme by selecting Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and
>   choose the GDB debugger for your debug scheme.

But really you ought to just update your tools.

Comment: I'm making an iOS6 app. When i would upgrade to Xcode 5, would this give me any problems?

Comment: thank you btw, the quick fix worked. If I finish this app i'll upgrade immediately! ;)

Comment: You can build for iOS 6 with Xcode 5 with 0 problems. You can build for iOS 5 even. I recommend it really, there are tons of improvements in Xcode 5, especially within IB and compilation speed and useful warnings.

Answer (score 1):

My standart debugging workflow - If error origin is unknown - comment out everything in AppDelegate methods  - mainly in  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

and in these also, if You have anything there:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Then - if You don't encounter crashing anymore, then start uncommenting stuff. Once You find  a code line (or code block)  that crashes, then look deeper in that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add an exceptions breakpoint to see where in your code it is crashing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html